# Load a set of pages one-by-one in a iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe

I'm trying to load a set of pages one-by-one, and load next when current request has finished,

Now in my example page, I got only one iframe,

`<iframe onload="loadNext()"></iframe>`

And I use the following script to do the job,

```
    var i = 0;

    function loadNext()
    {
        var urls = [
        'http://localhost/a.htm',
        'http://localhost/b.htm',
        'http://localhost/c.htm',
        ];

        if (i > urls.length - 1)
        {
            console.log ("Done!");
            return;
        }

        document.querySelector('iframe').src = urls[i ++];
    }
```

But the onload event was triggering too fast, I expected to see the 3 pages loaded in order, but it's not (From the `Network` tab in chromium browser), and I didn't even see the access log in nginx.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: So what happens? The pages loaded but in a different order?

Comment: @zeroflagL looks like it doesn't really "wait" for the current load progress, just jump to the next page immediately

Comment: But `loadNext()` is called four times and the last call prints "done"? Or doesn't that work either?

Comment: @zeroflagL it does print "done"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should work. I've tested this and also added a `timeout` before each frame load so you can see the change.

```
var URLs = [
    'http://localhost/a.htm',
    'http://localhost/b.htm',
    'http://localhost/c.htm',
    'http://localhost/d.htm'
];

function loadNext(){

    var frameWindow = document.getElementById('test').contentWindow;

    if(URLs.length > 0){
        setTimeout(function(){
            frameWindow.location.replace(URLs.shift());
        }, 1000);
    }
}

<iframe id="test" onload="loadNext();"></iframe>
```

Could it be that since you're loading from the `localhost`, the load time is so small you don't notice it?

Comment: +1 for setTimeout(), and I made a mistake, the c.html contains a iframe that loads b.html which confused me ...